# Execute jquery submit function for a specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, partial-views

I'm working on a Web Application that has 4 nav-tabs.

The main cshtml file called **index.cshtml** contains the 4 nav-tabs as partial views:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="mainTab" >
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="@ViewData["Stamp"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stempel-tab">
          @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
          @{Html.RenderAction("_Stempel", "Home");}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@ViewData["BackDated"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="backdated-tab">
          @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
           @{Html.RenderAction("_BackDated", "Home");}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@ViewData["History"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="historie-tab">
           @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
           @{Html.RenderAction("_Historie", "Home");}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@ViewData["ChangePin"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="changepin-tab">
           @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
           @{Html.RenderAction("_Pinaendern", "Home");}          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Each tab has a form, where I have to submit information. I use Html.BeginForm to define the Form:

@using (Html.BeginForm("SavePost", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

To execute the form I use a button (There is a diferent button for each tab):

```
<div class="stempel_button" id="my_centered_buttons">                              
   <button id="stempel" value="stempel" type="submit" style="width:200px"class="btn btn-primary" >@ViewData["Button_Booking"]</button>                    
</div>
```

When the button is pressed the function SavePost is called:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {     


            //Executed when pressed send/book
            $('#stempel').click(function () {

                alert("hello click stempel");

                $("form[action$='SavePost']").submit(function () {

                //Some Action
            }
     }
}
```

The function SavePost is defined in the HomeController.cs:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]       
        public String SavePost()
        { 
          // Some code
        }
```

When I click on the button submit in one tab it's executing this line in all the other tabs:

```
$("form[action$='SavePost']").submit(function () {

        //Some Action
  }
```

Is it possible to define an ID for every form and call the submit function with an ID, so it's only executing the specific form?

Like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SavePost", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "stempelform" }))
```

Thank you for your answer...

Comment: I need to use the same "SavePost" function to execute every form.

Comment: Your only issue is that `$("form[action$='SavePost']")` selects all four forms. Since you're hardcoding your click handlers anyway, you can use `$("form[action$='SavePost']").eq(0).submit();` to only submit the first form. Also note that `$(form).submit(handler);` sets the click handler but does not submit the form. And if you call `$(four forms).submit(handler);` you're setting `handler` to handle *all four* forms.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer. I have a question. How to define the index for each form?.

Comment: I added the index 0 to submit the first form. $("form[action$='SavePost']").eq(0).submit();  Now it's executing the SavePost action several times, every time I click the button is executing the function one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $("form[action$='SavePost']").eq(0).submit(); for each form works.

if you use a button condition like this one:

```
$("#buttonid").click(function () {
}
```

it will add a submit every time you click on the button. I just delete the condition and it works.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you need to insert `eq(0)`, `eq(1)`, etc. when setting the submit handler, or you will attach four handlers to each form.